# How to get error code of failed transaction

Tags: web3js, contract-development, metamask, error

I tried to use web3.eth.getTransaction, web3.eth.getTransactionReciept and try to get by block number.

Maximum, that I got - it's:

```
status: false
```

But I need to get "T3".
[image]